# why does scanf() input variable not output as the value it contains? instead it prints the memory location

Tags: c, printf, scanf, format-string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int valueEntered ,x;
   
    scanf("enter the value:%d",&valueEntered);

    x = valueEntered;

    printf("the value entered is:%d\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the input, expected output and the current output you are seeing. You also didn't ask any question (title is not question)

Comment: And it's not printing "the memory location". It's just printing some garbage value because `valueEntered` was not initialised and the `scanf` also failed as hinted in the second comment above.

Comment: You should always check the return value of `scanf`, in order to verify that it was successful, before attempting to use the result of the `scanf` operation. See this guide for further information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Answer (score 3):

Split this call of `scanf`

```
scanf("enter the value:%d",&valueEntered);
```

into calls of `printf` and `scanf`

```
printf( "enter the value " );
scanf("%d",&valueEntered);
```

Otherwise the call of `scanf` will try to find the string `"enter the value:"` in the input stream.

In general you should check whether a call of `scanf` was successful.

Answer (score 3):

The `scanf` operation will fail unless the user himself enters `"enter the value:"` followed by a number. However, you probably do not want the user to have to enter that string, but you instead want your program to print that string. Therefore, instead of

```
scanf("enter the value:%d",&valueEntered);
```

you should write:

```
printf( "Enter a value: " );
scanf( "%d", &valueEntered );
```

However, before using the result of a `scanf` operation, you should always check the return value of `scanf`, in order to verify that it was successful. Therefore, it would be better to write the following:

```
printf( "Enter a value: " );

if ( scanf( "%d", &valueEntered ) != 1 )
{
    printf( "Conversion failure!\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

//if we reach this line, then scanf was successful, and we
//can now use the value of the variable "valueEntered"
```

In your question, you wrote:

> instead it prints the memory location

It is not printing the memory location. Instead, it is printing garbage, i.e. it is printing whatever value `valueEntered` had before the `scanf` function call, because `scanf` did not assign a value to that variable.

If you change your program to the following, so that it checks the return value of `scanf`, then it will become obvious that `scanf` is failing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int valueEntered ,x;
   
    if ( scanf("enter the value:%d",&valueEntered) != 1 )
    {
        printf( "Conversion failure!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    x = valueEntered;

    printf("the value entered is:%d\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
65
Conversion failure!
```

However, if the user himself enters `"enter the value"` following by a number, then `scanf` succeeds:

```
enter the value:65
the value entered is:65
```

If you instead use the following program, then everything will work as it should:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int valueEntered, x;
   
    printf( "Enter a value: " );

    if ( scanf( "%d", &valueEntered ) != 1 )
    {
        printf( "Conversion failure!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    x = valueEntered;

    printf( "The value entered is: %d\n", x );

    return 0;
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
Enter a value: abc
Conversion failure!
```

```
Enter a value: 65
The value entered is: 65
```

As you can see, it is no longer necessary for the user himself to type `"enter the value:"` for the input to be accepted.